# Veracrypt Sufficient Enough for Firefox Profile

Tags: encryption, firefox, veracrypt

I was doing some reading about Firefox and using the password manager with a master password([1](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/146381/does-setting-a-firefox-master-password-make-sense-given-that-full-disk-encryptio?rq=1),[2](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/48174/if-i-use-a-good-master-password-in-firefox-is-security-improved-when-i-remember),[3](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/408/how-secure-are-my-passwords-in-the-hands-of-firefox-using-a-master-password?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

Suppose I want to protect my entire Firefox profile, is using [Veracrypt](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/) to create a container that uses AES(TwoFish(Serpent)) encryption and a 64-character password(numbers,letters, and symbols`(ex. <,.)($%))` stored in a KeePass database, good enough to store my Firefox profile?

The machine I'm doing this on is my home PC running Windows 10.

Comment: What is your threat model? Obviously when using Firefox, the profile will be accessible...

Comment: @RoryAlsop - Home PC. It's for local level encryption. When I leave my PC unattended, I lock it.